# Augment the type signature of a function's arguments if the current argument is a function and that function has properties

Tags: typescript

Accepting suggestions for a better title, in lieu of that I am outlining my exact use case

I am writing a library that allows for the remote execution of methods and accessing of properties behind a serialised boundary such as a Web Worker.

The general flow revolves around traversing the shape of your source object, function, array through a property/value "handle" expressed as an `IHandle` interface.

```
export interface IHandle<T> {
  property<K extends keyof T | ((...args: any) => any)>(key: K): K extends keyof T ? IHandle<T[K]> : any;
  exec(
    ...args: T extends (...args: any) => any ? Parameters<T> : any
  ): T extends (...args: any) => any ? Promise<IHandle<ReturnType<T>>> : any;
  value(): T extends (...args: any) => any ? any : Promise<T>;
  dispose(): Promise<void>;
}
```

This allows for the recursive typing of properties, meaning type signatures persist between handles.

```
type Source = { foo: { bar: 'foobar' }}
declare const handle: IHandle<Source>

// Accessing a property
const foobar: string = await handle.property('foo').property('bar').value()
```

The `IHandle` type can execute functions too, this will execute the function and send the value.

```
type Source = () => 'foo'
declare const handle: IHandle<Source>

const fooHandle: IHandle<string> = await handle.exec()
const foo: string = await fooHandle.value()
```

Functions can be passed basic properties too.

```
type Source = (foo: string) => foo
declare const handle: IHandle<Source>

const fooHandle: IHandle<string> = await handle.exec('foo')
const foo: string = await fooHandle.value()
```

The issue I am having is that when a function takes a callback which is supplied parameters, I am not sure how to adjust the type signature of `.exec()` so the properties on the callback are `IHandle` of the actual properties.

With the following source type:

```
type Source = (cb: (prop: string) => any) => cb('foo')
declare const handle: IHandle<Source>
```

What I want to see is:

```
const foo = await handle.exec(async (fooHandle: IHandle<string>) => {
    const foo = await fooHandle.value()
})
```

But what I get is:

```
/// fooHandle is the wrong type
const foo = await handle.exec(async (fooHandle: string) => {
    // ...
})
```

Finally, conditionally understanding if `exec` param type is a callback and changing it as required.

```
type Source = (one: string, cb: (prop: string) => any) => cb('foo')
declare const handle: IHandle<Source>

// Right now, fooHandle is a type string
const foo = await handle.exec('one', (fooHandle: IHandle<string>) => {
    //...
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQAlMkATAG2AB4AVAPjgG8BYAKDjjCgjDRgE8qAaTihUZAM5wA1sH4R0cGnAA%20cABTqAdDsxQA5hIBccEvwCUcALwMz5uutn8TQ8y9EhxpKU4VK4APwExGSUtADaQgC6DCZmANxsHKDA2OpJHHA6WnqGJspiwJIa2bnGpkgW1raVgXAACnqYALbAqFAStLEV-Blu-oXF2roG5XbVPXX13M0IEtREJBTUAEptAK5QSDT8vF103QkZAG6Y5OvA6v0FnkXeJSN5PZY2k0FmcCbTELPzXYnsOCkOaQeZXL4zObUY4QBCkOgAgC%20bDYoEgsDgzQgpHWlDgAEEmBkBLw4ABlCCbXDWDTYABGJgkMCgyH0LxqvUBpFS5D0eGwECQTLgAAsAAwmRahagUqnAOgowHirQpNIAcnQEAgavMbGRrFR4Gg8CxOLxACEiYCSXhZVBqVZaQyNJqIIzmaz2c8JmYMtzsLyoPzBcLxZKQssqHbcAqDUqxSqQKlNK7w0swkyWUh9HQvSxARwBUKIJQtOQIPp1K7dYDETX9Yb0Sbsbi8ABhK0cG3kyn2vCOxhwVNOkxVrXurNsn2VL0ffUcf2B4NC%20Bh4LpmW9mOKjjKrg8Pj8dQarU6xPJsdu9fSqiZ1m5ib5zJwIsSEvAMsVy81jh1vWKtFjUxFs8QAEU7OBu2jfsNEFYAJ1ZAAaF9nUvBDs1nGdp05BceT5F8Q1XCVr0jaDYwyZVVWPN9WhgEVWTVZC0JIjMPWzB9XifTJX3fT9K2rDI-1YBtWCAA)

Comment: I think i need to `infer` the return type extends a function?

Comment: I'm having trouble following this. Can you produce a minimum reproducible example on the TypeScript playground?

Comment: Yeah sorry - I am struggling to express the problem. I have a added a link to the bottom of the example.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But it still seems incomplete. What does `createHandle()` do?

Comment: It's just a factory function for an `IHandle<T>`. In the examples above, it creates a handle based on the source object above it. I'll change the question to use the same syntax as the playground as it's more clear

Comment: Have updated the question to remove `createHandle()` because it's not required. Also added a case to the playground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I 100% understand your use case, especially when it comes to what to do with the return type of the callback... for now I'm going to assume it stays the same.  Furthermore, I'm confused that `IHandle<T>` gets an `exec()` method even when `T` is not function-like.  That is, I really don't know what you plan to do if someone takes an `IHandle<{foo: string}>` and calls the `exec()` method, or any of the other edge cases that might occur.  Since you're not explicitly asking about that and your example code doesn't test that, I'll consider such issues outside the scope of the question in what follows.

---

My approach here would be to write a type alias `HandlifyParams<T>` that leaves a non-callback type `T` alone, but turns a callback type `T` into a new callback type whose parameters are each wrapped in `IHandle<>`, and whose return type is left alone (again, not sure if that's what you want):

```
type HandlifyParams<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ?
  (...args: { [I in keyof A]: IHandle<A[I]> }) => R : T;
```

Note how I am [mapping the tuple/array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) of `args`, which seems to be the main technique you might be missing in your code.

Now we can represent `IHandle<T>`'s `exec()` method's `args` as being another mapped tuple/array type which wraps each parameter with `HandlifyParams`:

```
export interface IHandle<T> {
  exec(
    ...args: (T extends (...args: infer A) => any ? {
      [I in keyof A]: HandlifyParams<A[I]>
    } : never)
  ): T extends (...args: any) => any ? Promise<IHandle<ReturnType<T>>> : any;
}
```

For a type `T` like `(x: string, y: number) => boolean`, the compiler will make `exec(x: string, y: number) => Promise<IHandle<boolean>>`, because `Handlify<string>` and `Handlify<number>` are just `string` and `number`, respectively.  But for a type `T` like `(x: string, f: (x: string) => number) => boolean`, the compiler will make `exec(x: string, f: (x: IHandle<string>) => number) => Promise<IHandle<boolean>>`, since `Handlify<(x: string) => number>` will modify its input to become `(x: IHandle<string>) => number`.

---

You can verify that your example tests now compile with no error.  Hooray!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsCWAzEAFOAnOAWwGcAeAFQD4oBeKcqCAD2AmWKgAoA6X-Ac2IAuKGgQYIeKAEEAlLWpiJUgEpQA-AFgAUFC69uA4VADeUANoBJUQigBrCCAD2GGQF0Rl+MhQRS0qzdqAF95Gmo1EXIAbh0dZjAnPGAbVjwMOABjaC9EVD8qUx09MDwnSGSQUgBpRhY2JA4HZ1cGAB8uHj48QRFEEDDqftlKTmaRatkJutZ2e0cXeg0oXJ8C82qgqD6EEFjdOohMzmK9KAMjEU4GZlnG-W7em2UZQah+5ZNTs4trMXmWu4RN5UJgcPgiGQApYgt8oMFtlAEBAAG6SWSnKZLW4NDhdQw9YzDBTvXbLbBlQhoYh+Vb5UgqCDAACueAQ5HABUo3MR-X2ehRcBQzIgnCxN3qc3xl1JAxJH3UssRFKcVJpFEo-KgSGpiRpYpEKrVfhRTjQSE1OmCcW0CSSKUITiQzN8MiKB1AkCgAGUnKzsrQuJkAEYiYjAPBifhvfqnJBHFD4aCZJwIcNQAAWAAZPCDfKRff6IJQbXps9xmEdOAByDBOJzVjHaa3aeJMRLJKCO52ugBC7r0nughbwAbonBDVzrTjDEajMd2C5AcYTSagKbTKWzuby+ZH2RLrYO5crx04053a1I4cjCH4lDeXwOeg3xCcvm4KCc-HP9abelCK0bTtTtuxdaAAGEBygIcfT9UdoDoMwLyDUMuBQm953lRdsJAeEV0yRM8GTVN023FY8z8fdi1LTMs24UpykkUAa2nRsKyYKtfxnCjdz8TC7wfEknx+V93wgT9v24-94SbFs2w7B0nXAqAABFoNg6jA04VMIFnW9+AAGnXNDuP0rDwllJcCKIkjNzoy96Wow9ThPTjjmrN9CCZDMo2rYyzN4q8BPvR84TEj8vx-acZMA5sbSAA)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I was trying to use the `keyof` syntax and wrapping the keys with an `Ihandle`, however I was having trouble assigning that as the `...args` of the callback type. Thank you for this. Your code example also helped me better understand the use of `infer`